# Building a 232x120 cm mirror closet door

Tags: doors, closet, mirror

I'm redoing my wardrobe doors, and decided to have 2 massive sliding doors (each 232x120 cm), one of which will be a mirror. These will be mounted in a hanging fashion to a rail above that's rated for 60 kg. I've calculated the total weight of the mirror door, and it's going to be pretty heavy:

1. 27 kg for a 4mm mirror
2. 38 kg for an 18mm birch plywood

That's already over 60 kg. Over that, I think that the plywood might warp over time (but I'm not sure).

What're my options here?

- Should I have a frame for the mirror instead? Perhaps an aluminium frame (Ikea does it that way).
- Should I build a frame with the plywood instead of having a huge piece of plywood?
- If I reduce the plywood thickness down to 14mm, the weights will be alright, but will 14mm plywood warp?

EDIT: Is plexiglass a potential solution?

Comment: If you want "massive mirror door" you might want to consider a rail with more capacity. My experience with plexiglas is that it will look great if nobody lives in or uses the house, and it will be a scratched up ugly mess as soon as it's exposed to real life (and a big sheet like that will warp providing funhouse mirror effects unless it's thick & heavy itself, or mounted to a solid backing...)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: An acrylic mirror would be less than half the 27 kilos you've indicated.  Would one of those suit your purpose, or must you have glass?

Comment: Yes, however, acrylic mirrors are prone to distortions. However, I've ordered a sample 110x30 cm acrylic mirror with a thickness of 5mm that's supposed to not warp as much.